# Not able to apply `interface` in the class

Tags: angular7, typescript2.0

I create a model for assign a "language" as like this:

```
export interface ModelLang {
    lang:string;
}
```

same has been added with app state as like :

```
import { ModelLang } from "./shared-components/state/models";

export interface AppState {
    lang:ModelLang
}
```

But when i use in the app component assigning a string getting error as `Eng not assignable to type ModelLang` - here what is the type goes wrong?

app.component.ts:

/**
* Keeping nearly ideal. just keeping for router loading purpose.
*
*importing jquery for app!!
*/

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from "@ngrx/store";
import { AppState } from "./app.state";
import { Lang } from "./shared-components/state/shared.actions";
import { ModelLang } from "./shared-components/state/models";
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    lang:ModelLang = "Eng"; //throws error

    constructor(private store:Store<AppState>){}

    ngOnInit(){
    }


}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-scw7eu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to assign a string to a typed variable, try the following.

> lang:ModelLang = { lang: "Eng" };

Comment: How to make string interface?

Comment: you can use type string directly like:
`lang: string = "Eng"`